# why does this file get saved over ? fileI/O python3

Tags: file-io, python-3.x

Why does this replace whats already in the file and how can i get so it doesnt.
(should i just use .write .read instead of json ?)

```
def load():
    with open("random_number_highscores.txt","r") as x:
        print (json.load(x))

def save(a):
    with open("random_number_highscores.txt", "w") as x:
        json.dump(a, x)
    print ("saved.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because you opening the file in "write" mode. When opening a file in write mode Python will overwrite everything already inside the file and add the new content you wish to write to the file. Instead open the file in "append" mode to add content to the already existing content within the file.

Example:

```
with open("file.txt","a") as file:
    file.write("This text was appended to the file")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing to file with 'w' (write) flag, try 'a' (append):

```
def save(a):
  with open("random_number_highscores.txt", "a") as x:
    json.dump(a, x)
  print ("saved.")
```